# Restler get/index with optional value

Tags: php, restler

I'm trying to define a method with Restler so that if I do `.../clients/123` then it returns that specific client, and if I leave off the 123 then it returns all clients.  I tried this:

```js
/**
 * @param int $id The SQL identifier 
 */
function index($id = NULL) {
}
```

If I do it like that, then it works with query params:  `.../clients?id=123`

Then when I add `{@from path}` to the end of that @param so that I do use a query string, it doesn't work with no value specified, but does with with the 123 specifier.  What's the right way to do this so that I have it as a path instead of a query parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as a best practise reserve index for getting a collection and use get for specific id 
as shown below

```
function index(){
    return Client::all()->toArray();
}

function get($id){
    return Client::find($id)->toArray();
}
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you for the continued great support of your tool!  I was misunderstanding how that index method was supposed to be used.